# GStreamer SDK: "playbin2" creation fails on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, playback, gstreamer

I'd like to use GStreamer in my Android application. So far, I can already create `GstNetClock` and use it successfully.

If I try to create a `playbin2` element, the factory always returns `NULL`. My code:

```
GstElement* player = gst_element_factory_make("playbin2", NULL);
```

The relevant lines of *jni/Android.mk*:

```
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS    := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) \
                        $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) \
                        $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) \
                        $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) \
                        $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS)

GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS := gstreamer-net-0.10 \
                        gstreamer-interfaces-0.10 \
                        gstreamer-video-0.10 \
                        gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10
```

In addition I tried to increase log verbosity of GStreamer to `GST_LEVEL_LOG`. However no logs are shown at all (as with default settings).

Do I have to load additional plugins or libraries? Or should I configure anything differently?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you can run at command prompt `gst-inspect-0.10 playbin2`. You might have an earlier deprecated version which is playbin. Try running that also.

A: Don't think you will require extra plugins as playbin2 is part of  `gst-plugins-base`